# User Authentication (Using sha1)

Tags: php, sql, encryption

I am creating a login form. I am learning how to use SHA-1 to encrypt passwords. I used SHA-1 to encrypt the password that the user created during registration. In the database I inputted pretend username and password data, to have something to work with. I'm having problems getting my login form to work.

```
// Database Connection

$con = getConnection();

$sqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from Customers
                         WHERE Email = '$email' and Password = sha1('$passLogin')") 

// Executing query
$result = $con->mysql_result($sqlQuery, "0");

if ($result == 0) {
    echo "Can not login, try again.";
} else {
    echo "Login Good!";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the password is SHA1 hashed in the database already? It's also common to do the hash in PHP rather than MySQL.

Comment: Don't forget to use a random salt to ensure that the same password is hashed to different values for different people.

Comment: @philfreo, i'm pretty new in using SHA1. what i see in the database looks already hashed. i made some pretend accounts when i filled out my own registration form. and the passwords stored in the database, are not the passwords i made up, but are 40 characters long with random letters and numbers.

Comment: Please consider whether SHA1 is really the right thing to use. The article "Enough With The Rainbow Tables: What You Need To Know About Secure Password Schemes" is food for thought: http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am learning how to use sha1 to
>   encrypt passwords.

... use sha1 to *hash* passwords. Hashing is different from encryption. Encryption is reversible, hashing isn't. (or shouldn't be). Now, ...

1. You have to make sure the passwords in the database are hashed.
2. Usually you do the hashing on the PHP side.
3. You should use salting to make rainbow table attacks unfeasible. Read [Just Hashing is Far from Enough for Storing Password](http://www.kavoir.com/2010/03/just-hashing-is-far-from-enough-how-to-position-against-dictionary-and-rainbow-attacks.html)

That said, I would do the authentication part like this:

```
$hashedAndSalted = sha1($passLogin . $yourSalt);

$sqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT Email FROM Customers WHERE Email = '$email' AND Password = '$hashedAndSalted'");

if (mysql_num_rows($sqlQuery) == 1) {
    echo 'Login successful';
} else  {
    echo 'Could not login';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a separate note if you have not sanitized your form inputs you are wide open for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

If user enters the following for Email field:

```
' or '1'='1
```

They will be logged in :)

You should be using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape `$email` and `$passLogin` or even better use prepared statements.

Comment: How do you know `$email` and `$passLogin` haven't been properly sanitized?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your query with this:

```
$sqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from Customers
                WHERE Email = '".$email."' and Password = '".sha1($passLogin)."'");
```

Remember to always concatenate strings and variables manually, don't rely on PHP to do it for you. Also, you forgot the semicolon `;` after that line. Every line must be appended with a semicolon in PHP.

Comment: No it's not, having sha1() in a string doesn't execute the method.

Comment: Yes it is. You'll always generate the same hash because you are hashing a constant. Also what's up with the "Remember to always concatenate strings and variables manually, don't rely on PHP to do it for you."? This is terrible advice.

Comment: It's not terrible advice, as it prevents errors. It doesn't hash a constant, though, while the code before I edited it did hash the wrong password, it wasn't a constant: e.g:
$foo = 'bar';
echo "'$foo'";
outputs 'bar' (with quotes)

Comment: @Andrew Of course it was a constant. Variables in single quotes are not interpolated.

Comment: Touche. This is why I concatenate using the '.' operator.